# Not able to use temporary column created using Cross apply in Left Join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cross-apply

I have used Cross apply to Flip data from Wide to Tall format. Used answer from following question to implement [Using PIVOT to Flip Data from Wide to Tall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531560/using-pivot-to-flip-data-from-wide-to-tall)

I have created temporary column `Sector`. I want to use this column for Left Join with another table. But i am getting error `Invalid column name 'Sector'` on this line `V.Sector = S.[Sector name]`

```
SELECT Date,
      Country,
      Sector,
      PE,
      PX_BOOK
      S.Sector_level
FROM [Economic_Data].[dbo].[Sector_Valuations] V
CROSS APPLY 
(
  VALUES
    ('Large Cap Equity',[Large Cap Equity_PE],[Large Cap Equity_book]),
    ('Mid Cap Equity',[Mid Cap Equity_PE],[Mid Cap Equity_book]),
    ('Small Cap Equity',[Small Cap Equity_PE],[Small Cap Equity_book]),
    ('Value Index',[Value Index_PE],[Value Index_book]),
    ('Growth Index',[Growth Index_PE],[Growth Index_book]),
    )  x (Sector, PE, PX_BOOK)  
 Left join [Economic_Data].[dbo].[Sector level] S
 on  V.Sector = S.[Sector name]
```

Can anybody help me to fix this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the `cross apply` alias:

```
[Economic_Data].[dbo].[Sector level] S
on V.Sector = x.[Sector name] 
--------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

Its looks like you need remove the last comma.

```
SELECT Date,
      Country,
      Sector,
      PE,
      PX_BOOK
      S.Sector_level
FROM [Economic_Data].[dbo].[Sector_Valuations] V
CROSS APPLY 
(
  VALUES
    ('Large Cap Equity',[Large Cap Equity_PE],[Large Cap Equity_book]),
    ('Mid Cap Equity',[Mid Cap Equity_PE],[Mid Cap Equity_book]),
    ('Small Cap Equity',[Small Cap Equity_PE],[Small Cap Equity_book]),
    ('Value Index',[Value Index_PE],[Value Index_book]),
    ('Growth Index',[Growth Index_PE],[Growth Index_book])--, <------
    )  x (Sector, PE, PX_BOOK)  
 Left join [Economic_Data].[dbo].[Sector level] S
 on  V.Sector = S.[Sector name]
```