# SQL- get data from two tables in different columns without using unions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `STOCK` that looks like this:

```
PRODUCT   SALES_CODE  STOCK_1    STOCK_2    STOCK_3
-----------------------------------------------------
A         6-10        0          1          2
```

There are many `STOCK_X` buckets but for simplicity's sake, I've excluded.

Now I have another table `SIZE_GRID`:

```
SALES_CODE    SIZE_1   SIZE_2   SIZE_3
--------------------------------------
6-10          6        8        10
```

As you might have guessed, these are stock on hand for a certain product, by size.

I need to get the STOCK values from the first table, and the size from the second table.
Originally, I was doing the following

```
SELECT
  STOCK.PRODUCT,
  SIZE_GRID.SIZE_1,
  STOCK.STOCK_1
FROM
  STOCK
INNER JOIN
  SIZE_GRID ON
  SIZE_GRID.SALES_CODE = STOCK.SALES_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT
  STOCK.PRODUCT,
  SIZE_GRID.SIZE_2,
  STOCK.STOCK_2
FROM
  STOCK
INNER JOIN
  SIZE_GRID ON
  SIZE_GRID.SALES_CODE = STOCK.SALES_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT
  STOCK.PRODUCT,
  SIZE_GRID.SIZE_3,
  STOCK.STOCK_3
FROM
  STOCK
INNER JOIN
  SIZE_GRID ON
  SIZE_GRID.SALES_CODE = STOCK.SALES_CODE
```

I have around 40 STOCK_X that I need to retrieve, so wandering if there is a much easier way to do this? Preferably I want to use pure SQL and no UDF/SP's.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f323e

Comment: Besides being tedious, what is the problem with the above approach wrapped into a view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or later version, you could try the following method (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591818/transpose-or-unpivot-every-other-column/13593734#13593734)):

```
SELECT
  STOCK.PRODUCT,
  X.SIZE,
  X.STOCK
FROM
  STOCK
INNER JOIN
  SIZE_GRID ON
  SIZE_GRID.SALES_CODE = STOCK.SALES_CODE
CROSS APPLY (
  VALUES
    (SIZE_GRID.SIZE_1, STOCK.STOCK_1),
    (SIZE_GRID.SIZE_2, STOCK.STOCK_2),
    (SIZE_GRID.SIZE_3, STOCK.STOCK_3)
) X (SIZE, STOCK)
;
```

With a small tweak you could make it work in SQL Server 2005 as well:

```
SELECT
  STOCK.PRODUCT,
  X.SIZE,
  X.STOCK
FROM
  STOCK
INNER JOIN
  SIZE_GRID ON
  SIZE_GRID.SALES_CODE = STOCK.SALES_CODE
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT SIZE_GRID.SIZE_1, STOCK.STOCK_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SIZE_GRID.SIZE_2, STOCK.STOCK_2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SIZE_GRID.SIZE_3, STOCK.STOCK_3
) X (SIZE, STOCK)
;
```

However, if you are using an even earlier version, this might be of help:

```
SELECT
  STOCK.PRODUCT,
  SIZE  = CASE X.N
            WHEN 1 THEN SIZE_GRID.SIZE_1
            WHEN 2 THEN SIZE_GRID.SIZE_2
            WHEN 3 THEN SIZE_GRID.SIZE_3
          END,
  STOCK = CASE X.N
            WHEN 1 THEN STOCK.STOCK_1
            WHEN 2 THEN STOCK.STOCK_2
            WHEN 3 THEN STOCK.STOCK_3
          END,
FROM
  STOCK
INNER JOIN
  SIZE_GRID ON
  SIZE_GRID.SALES_CODE = STOCK.SALES_CODE
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3
) X (N)
;
```

Although the last two options use UNION ALL, they are combining single rows only, not entire subsets

Comment: Worked great. Not only was it much cleaner (from 600 lines to 100 lines), it was also much quicker than unions (from 7 seconds to <1 second). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider normalizing the table.  Instead of a repeating column:

```
PRODUCT   SALES_CODE  STOCK_1    STOCK_2    STOCK_3
```

Use a normalized table:

```
PRODUCT   SALES_CODE   STOCK_NO   STOCK
```

And the same for the SIZE_GRID table:

```
SALES_CODE    SIZE_NO   SIZE
```

Now you can query without the need to list 40 columns:

```
select  *
from    STOCK s
join    SIZE_GRID sg
on      sg.SALES_CODE = s.SALES_CODE
        and sg.SIZE_NO = s.STOCK_NO
```

Comment: Not an option. It is a very old legacy system.

Comment: @Lock Consider normalizing. I think that is the only way to achieve this and preferably a better way.

Comment: Not possible as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives you can use:

- Execute each SQL separately and merge and sort the result sets within your program
- Join the tables.
- Use a scalar subquery.

> select
>   select col1, col2, col3 from Table_1 q1,
>
> select col1, col2,
>   col3 from Table_2 q2  from  dual;

- Try UNION using FULL OUTER JOIN with the NVL function:  It is suggested that this has faster performance than the UNION operator.

> ```
> select
>     empno,
>     ename,
>      nvl(dept.deptno,emp.deptno) deptno, dname from emp
> full outer join 
> dept 
> on
>     (emp.deptno = dept.deptno) 
> order by 1,2,3,4;
> ```